# Creating Patches when x-axis uses datetime coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm generating some plots based on data that I'm holding in a pandas DataFrame; a snapshot of what this data (call it `data`)looks like is below:

```
                     CIG  CLD  DPT  OBV  P06  P12  POS  POZ  Q06  Q12  TMP  \
2010-10-01 18:00:00    8   CL   54    N  NaN  NaN    0    0  NaN  NaN   85   
2010-10-01 21:00:00    8   CL   50    N  NaN  NaN    0    0  NaN  NaN   89   
2010-10-02 00:00:00    8   CL   51    N    0  NaN    0    0    0  NaN   81   
2010-10-02 03:00:00    8   CL   52    N  NaN  NaN    0    0  NaN  NaN   67   
2010-10-02 06:00:00    8   CL   52    N    0  NaN    0    0    0  NaN   62   
2010-10-02 09:00:00    8   CL   51    N  NaN  NaN    0    0  NaN  NaN   59   
...
```

The idea for one of the plots is to overlay traces of the `TMP` and `DPT` fields (generated by using `data['TMP'].plot()`) on top of shading corresponding to the `CLD` field. So for instance, the block of time between `2010-10-01 18:00:00`-`2010-10-01 19:30:00` might be a light gray, and if the next entry for `CLD` were something else other than "CL", then the block `2010-10-01 19:30:00`-`2010-10-01 22:30:00` might be a darker color, that way I can see how the `CLD` field changes contemporaneously with the other fields.

My idea was to use a `Rectangle` patch from `matplotlib.Patches` to accomplish this shading. Since I'm basing the bounds on of the plot on the trace of `TMP` and `DPT`, I'll always know exactly what the height of the patch is, and I also always know its left boundary and its width - but the wrinkle is that I know them in `datetime` coordinates, not in x-y coordinates. So, if `bnd_left` is the left boundary as a `datetime`, `ylo` and `height` are floats, and `width` is a `datetime.timedelta`, I'm trying to make a patch like,

```
shading_patch = Rectangle([bnd_left, ylo], width, height)
```

But this doesn't work. There is a `TypeError` when the patch tries to create itself, since one cannot add a `float` and a `datetime.timedelta`. In the documentation, I can't find anything on how to transform the `datetime` coordinates to floats in the native transform of the plot I created by using the `DataFrame.plot()` method when I created the traces I'm trying to draw underneath.

Is there any simple way to draw patches on those plots generated with `DataFrame.plot()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some more digging a much easier solution came up - use the `axvspan`method. There is a caveat, though. In Pandas v. 0.12, if you slice through a `DataFrame` or `Timeseries` using the `.ix` attribute, for some weird reason you screw up the formatting into x-axis dates. When you plot, you must plot with `my_dataframe.plot(ax=ax, x_compat=True)` and configure the ticks yourself, or the shading from `axvspan` won't work.